# how create shared web from in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, webforms

I am working on asp.net application for reporting. I need to develop round about 50+ reports. On each report I need selection criteria that may contain start-date , end-date, name , company etc on almost every .aspx page. these controls can be of type like dropdown, textbox or calender etc .

Any idea to use one editable + shared (not 100% same) web form on every page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ASP.NET custom controls will allow you to create a module that you can insert into all of your pages.

You can also check this out to get you started more quickly.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1739/User-controls-in-ASP-NET

If you want to make it similar but not 100% same for all apps then just create public properties that you can use to adjust control properties on different pages. For example if some text box should be visible on some page and not visible on other just create a public property in your control named something like EnableTextBoxABC

Answer (score 1):

You can create [ASP.NET Custom Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt27tfhy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).